# Bash: Echoing a echo command with a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, echo

Ok, here is one I am struggling with as we speak. Echoing a echo command with a variable.

```
echo "creating new script file."
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $servsfile
echo "read -p "Please enter a service: " ser " >> $servfile
echo "servicetest=`getsebool -a | grep ${ser}` " >> $servfile
echo "if [ $servicetest > /dev/null ];then " >> $servfile
echo "echo "we are now going to work with ${ser}" " >> $servfile
echo "else" >> $servfile
echo "exit 1" >> $servfile
echo "fi" >> $servfile
```

My goal is create a script using echo commands then run it later. I just need to figure out how to echo echo/read commands while maintaining my variables.

edit: the variables need to transfer what's inside of them into the new file.

Comment: Consider using a "heredoc".  For this purpose, much easier.  Less quoting to do.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The immediate problem is you have is with quoting: **by using *double* quotes (`"..."`), your variable references are *instantly* expanded**, which is probably not what you want.

**Use *single* quotes** instead - strings inside single quotes are not expanded or interpreted in any way by the shell.

(If you want *selective* expansion inside a string - i.e., expand some variable references, but not others - do use double quotes, but prefix the `$` of references you do *not* want expanded with `\`; e.g., `\$var`).

However, **you're better off using a single *here-doc[ument]***, which allows you to *create multi-line `stdin` input on the spot*, bracketed by two instances of a self-chosen *delimiter*, the opening one prefixed by `<<`, and the closing one on a line by itself - starting at the very first column; search for `Here Documents` in `man bash` or at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html.

**If you *quote* the here-doc *delimiter* (`EOF` in the code below), variable references are also *not* expanded**. As @chepner points out, you're free to choose the *method* of quoting in this case: enclose the delimiter in single quotes *or* double quotes, *or* even simply arbitrarily escape one character in the delimiter with `\`:

```
echo "creating new script file."

cat <<'EOF'  > "$servfile"
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter a service: " ser
servicetest=`getsebool -a | grep ${ser}` 
if [ $servicetest > /dev/null ]; then 
  echo "we are now going to work with ${ser}"
else
  exit 1
fi
EOF
```

As @BruceK notes, you can *prefix your here-doc delimiter with `-`* (applied to this example: `<<-"EOF"`) in order to *have leading **tabs** stripped*, allowing for indentation that makes the actual content of the here-doc easier to discern.
Note, however, that this only works with actual *tab* characters, not leading spaces.

Employing this technique combined with the afterthoughts regarding the script's content below, we get (again, note that actual *tab* chars. must be used to lead each here-doc content line for them to get stripped):

```
cat <<-'EOF' > "$servfile"
    #!/bin/bash
    read -p "Please enter a service name: " ser
    if [[ -n $(getsebool -a | grep "${ser}") ]]; then 
      echo "We are now going to work with ${ser}."
    else
      exit 1
    fi
EOF
```

Finally, note that in `bash` even *normal single- or double-quoted strings can span multiple lines*, but you won't get the benefits of tab-stripping or line-block scoping, as *everything* inside the quotes becomes part of the string.

Thus, note how in the following `#!/bin/bash` has to follow the opening `'` *immediately* in order to become the first line of output:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter a service: " ser
servicetest=$(getsebool -a | grep "${ser}")
if [[ -n $servicetest ]]; then 
  echo "we are now going to work with ${ser}"
else
  exit 1
fi' > "$servfile"
```

---

Afterthoughts regarding the contents of your script:

- The syntax `$(...)` is preferred over `` `...` `` for command substitution nowadays.
- You should double-quote `${ser}` in the `grep` command, as the command will likely break if the value contains embedded spaces (alternatively, make sure that the valued read contains no spaces or other shell metacharacters).
- Use `[[ -n $servicetest ]]` to test whether `$servicetest` is empty (or perform the command substitution directly inside the conditional) - `[[ ... ]]` - the preferred form in `bash` - protects you from breaking the conditional if the `$servicetest` happens to have embedded spaces; there's NEVER a need to suppress stdout output inside a conditional (whether `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`, as no stdout output is passed through; thus, the `> /dev/null` is redundant (that said, with a command substitution inside a conditional, *stderr* output IS passed through).

Comment: cat <<'EOF'  >> "$servfile"
.
.
EOF
I had to do this in order for it to work!

Answer (score 26):

You just need to use single quotes:

```
$ echo "$TEST"
test
$ echo '$TEST'
$TEST
```

Inside single quotes special characters are not special any more, they are just normal characters.

Comment: But you definitely have to deal with sad characters after that :D

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "echo "we are now going to work with ${ser}" " >> $servfile
```

Escape all " within quotes with \. Do this with variables like \$servicetest too:

```
echo "echo \"we are now going to work with \${ser}\" " >> $servfile    
echo "read -p \"Please enter a service: \" ser " >> $servfile
echo "if [ \$servicetest > /dev/null ];then " >> $servfile
```

Comment: That first line looks kind-of dodgey.  If you want them in the result script, you need to quote them.  Or just use a "heredoc", as I suggested.

Comment: Got it. heredoc is a way better solution to this problem.  Just learned about it from this post and will use it going forward..Thx!!